# Call Grandparent Method without executing parent method through Mixin

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I need to override Parent method and call Grandparent method through mixin. Is it possible?

For example: `A` and `B` are library classes.

```
class A(object):
    def class_name(self):
        print "A"


class B(A):
    def class_name(self):
        print "B"
        super(B, self).class_name()
    # other methods ...
```

Now I need to override `class_name` method from `B` and call it's super.

```
class Mixin(object):
    def class_name(self):
        print "Mixin"
        # need to call Grandparent class_name instead of parent's
        # super(Mixin, self).class_name()


class D(Mixin, B):
    # Here I need to override class_name method from B and call B's super i.e. A's class_name, 
    # It is better if I can able to do this thourgh Mixin class. (
    pass
```

Now when I called `D().class_name()`, it should print `"Mixin" and "A"`only. Not "B"

Comment: Could probably be done using the `mro` (method resolution order) but I think it would break if you wrote `class D(B, Mixin)`.

Comment: solution: http://pastebin.com/k57Bipk2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use [`inspect.getmro()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmro) but that is likely to break if the user writes `class D(B, Mixin)`.

Let me demonstrate:

```
class A(object):
    def class_name(self):
        print "A"


class B(A):
    def class_name(self):
        print "B"
        super(B, self).class_name()
    # other methods ...

class Mixin(object):
    def class_name(self):
        print "Mixin"
        # need to call Grandparent class_name instead of parent's
        # super(Mixin, self).class_name()


class D(Mixin, B):
    # Here I need to override class_name method from B and call B's super i.e. A's class_name, 
    # It is better if I can able to do this thourgh Mixin class. (
    pass

class E(B, Mixin): pass
```

```
import inspect
print inspect.getmro(D) # returns tuple with (D, Mixin, B, A, object)
print inspect.getmro(E) # returns tuple with (E, B, A, Mixin, object)
```

So if you have control and can ensure that you always get `Mixin` first. You can use `getmro()` to get the grandparent and execute it's `class_name` function.